# Windows Server slow shared folder access

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, sql-server, exchange, windows-sbs-2011

We have a Windows Small Business Server 2011 which acts as an Active Directory, DNS, Exchange and File server. (Update: and SQL server as well)

More than 2 times a day the server becomes slow to respond to file access requests. The whole server looks like it's not responding to anything, sometimes the internet hangs as well (probably cause too slow DNS responses). It happens randomly, the users notice them, but there's usually no admin at site to look after the issue.

The logs dont show anything particular which can be easily connected to the slowdowns.

The performance monitor's tests shows too little memory (340Mb of 16GB) and too much paging per sec (it suggests we need more RAM) and too long average HDD queue length (3).

The memory is mostly used by exchange (7,5 Gb), and it is said to be normal to have it that way.

Do you have any ideas how can I stop the hangs happening, and speed up our server? Is it some software error or we just need more ram, better CPU?

Comment: Is the timing of the slowdowns consistent?  Have you checked for scheduled tasks, scans, or anything of that sort?  Do you have automatic updates enabled?  Do you have perfmon set up to track CPU, Memory, Swap, and disk utilisation?  Tracking the performance of those things may help narrow down what's causing the problem.

Comment: No, they are not consistent, and the scheduled tasks are groupped in the evening. The automatic updates are downloading, but not applied automatically.  I'll try to set up the performance monitor using a microsoft technet article. I'll write if there are any results!

Comment: It seems, that we have slow hard disk access (avg read time - mp/read), and not enough memory (high cached bytes). I'll try reconfiguring the virus scanner, checking the RAID array and adding more memory. We also have high handles count (around 60000), and I'm not sure what to do with it, I'll try to shut down unnecessary services. I can say for sure there is no network bottleneck. I will write back as soon as there is something new info, but I'm happy to read more suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL and the Exchange try to grab all the available memory by design. Not a good idea to put them on the same machine. In small business installations it is advised to limit the resources they can use.

In my case limiting the Exchange memory usage by 2GB was enough.

Unfortunately I haven't found any rule of thumb guidelines how much resources these softwares need. I saw someone used 4GB ram for an Exchange server with 200 user...